# how to extract 10 digit phone number from a cell in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract, phone-number

I have multiple rows on Google sheet, each cell in the row contains emails messages which have loads of text and symbols etc and also phone numbers, I need to extract these phone numbers, the phone numbers are 10 digits no spaces.

I tried regexextract on google sheet but it gives me only the first number

`=REGEXEXTRACT(E2,"\d+")`

how do I extract multiple phone numbers data which are present in each cell on Google sheet.

Comment: Add at least one example of the complete values that appear in the spreadsheet cells or a print with example values, making it easier to see.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "\D+", " "), " "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

player0's answer is already good. But if you only need to extract 10 digit numbers and not include other numbers in the cell (e.g. `123`), make sure to exclude the non-10 digit numbers.

I did modify the other answer to filter out those non-10 digit numbers using another `regexreplace` before using `split`.

#### Formula:

```
=split(regexreplace(regexreplace(A1,"\D+", " "), 
"^\d{1,9}\s|\s\d{1,9}\s|\s\d{1,9}$|\d{11,}"
, " "), " ")
```

#### Patterns to exclude:

We need to exclude any numbers that aren't 10 succeeding digits. These are the following possible patterns.

1. `^\d{1,9}\s` less than 10 numbers at the start
2. `\s\d{1,9}\s` less than 10 number in between
3. `\s\d{1,9}$` less than 10 numbers at the end
4. `\d{11,}` more than 10 numbers

Appending them all using `|` resulting into `"^\d{1,9}\s|\s\d{1,9}\s|\s\d{1,9}$|\d{11,}"`

#### Sample Cell Value:

`123asd1234567890oia123joieqw9876543210asda123asd12345678910`

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

It seems it is having an issue on multiple occurrences when the string has spaces in between. If script is an option, I do recommend this one below.

#### Code:

```
function get10DigitNums(string) {
  var regex = /[^\w](\d{10})[^\w]|^(\d{10})[^w]|[^w](\d{10})$/g;
  var result = [];
  do {
    m = regex.exec(string);
    if (m) {
      m.shift();
      result.push(m);
    }
  } while (m);
  return [result.flat().filter(Boolean)];
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi this was helpful, in output i got few more cells with some have 4, 6, and 10 digit data extracted from the messge, is there a way to filter this data further, maybe selecting all cells and clearing out the cells having less than 10 digit numbers, I'm sharing screen shot  [link](http://shorturl.at/efoLM)

Comment: Hi @Maximus, please see the modified answer. I do recommend using script instead as I am unable to make it work for formula alone.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do sth similar (extract all phone numbers removing spaces and letters/ other symbols) and I think I found an easier solution:

=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(F3;"[^[:digit:]]";""))

Example:

F3 = "32 3215-2263" ====> Result "3232152263"

Hope it helps.